# Request Entity Too Large : Apache to JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: jboss-eap-6

We are upgrading from JBoss 5.1 to JBoss 6.2.  Using Apache/2.2.15 to pass through to JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA on RHEL 6 box.  App was working correctly on my local, I was going directly to JBoss.  In our dev env, I get the entity too large error now.  We utilize SSO for apps and I'm guessing it's this object that cuasing the issue.  We have a few other apps that use regular authentication and they work fine.  Only SSO apps fail.

I added the suggested max_packet_size parm:

```
###---------workers.properties
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

### Define template worker
worker.template.port=8009
worker.template.type=ajp13
worker.template.ping_mode=A
worker.template.reply_timeout=10000
worker.template.socket_connect_timeout=10000
worker.template.connection_pool_timeout=600
###Added to remove ajp entity size issue
worker.template.max_packet_size=65536

### Referencing the template worker properties makes the workers.properties shorter and more concise.
worker.fenlxmtd03.reference=worker.template
worker.fenlxmtd03.host=127.0.0.1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=fenlxmtd03
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=True

worker.status.type=status
###workers.properties----------
```

Now I get the following error in mod_jk.log

[Thu May 15 11:35:14 2014][25185:140362161276896] [info] ajp_handle_cping_cpong::jk_ajp_common.c (913): timeout in reply cpong
[Thu May 15 11:35:14 2014][25185:140362161276896] [info] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1562): (fenlxmtd03) failed sending request, socket -1 prepost cping/cpong failure (errno=24)
[Thu May 15 11:35:14 2014][25185:140362161276896] [info] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1619): (fenlxmtd03) all endpoints are disconnected, detected by connect check (0), cping (1), send (0)
[Thu May 15 11:35:14 2014]loadbalancer dev6.internal.travelhq.com 0.004168
[Thu May 15 11:35:14 2014][25186:140362161276896] [info] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1619): (fenlxmtd03) all endpoints are disconnected, detected by connect check (1), cping (0), send (0)
[Thu May 15 11:35:14 2014]loadbalancer dev6.internal.travelhq.com 0.001673

In JBoss 5.1, we made the corresponding change to the tomcat server.xml file.  I'm looking in the new standalone.xml and not sure where to add it.  Found this section below...am I close?

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009" />
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it through Red Hat support.

The packet size is now set through the org.apache.coyote.ajp.MAX_PACKET_SIZE system property on EAP 6.  That can be set through the command line at start up, for example:

./standalone.sh ... -Dorg.apache.coyote.ajp.MAX_PACKET_SIZE=65536

Or it can be set through the system properties block in your standalone.xml.  You can place that in between the extensions and management block, for example:

```
</extensions>

<system-properties>
<property name="org.apache.coyote.ajp.MAX_PACKET_SIZE" value="65536"/>
</system-properties>

<management>
```